# if checkbox is checked change the value using PHP

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying to accomplish one simple task (but is not simple for me).

I have a form and I'm having a trouble with this check box.

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="b"  
<?php if (isset($_POST[b])) echo "value='y'"; else echo "value='n'"; ?>/>
```

I'm not sure if I use the right one, but it doesn't work for me.

So basically I want the value of the `input` of `b` will be `y` if the checkbox is checked else it will always be `n` if the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: That isn't how a checkbox works.  The checkbox posts a value when selected or nothing at all. Perhaps you want the radio input?

Comment: are you new to web technology

Comment: Are you submitting the page to itself?

Comment: @Somebodyisintrouble yeah I forgot to put this is `homework`

Comment: @FabrícioMatté yes `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF')`

Comment: @sachleen has already fixed your code per se (at least for what you asked). However, I still don't see much use to this - changing the `value` attribute after submission for what? The checkbox's `value` attribute is not displayed to the end-user, and if you want to store different values based on whether your user checked the checkbox or not, you'd do that check somewhere else.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté I wnat to store thier option in`mysql` that is why :(

Comment: Yes, then you would be putting the `if (isset($_POST[b]))` check before your `insert`/`update` query. `=]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use two conditions one is for showing checked/unchecked and second for showing y/n

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="b" <?php echo (isset($_POST['b'])?"value='y'":"value='n'")?> 
 <?php echo (isset($_POST['b'])?"checked":"") ?>  />
```

Answer (score 4):

That's not how a checkbox works.

It's checked when the `checked` attribute is there.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" checked /> Checked
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" /> NOT Checked
```

So you want to use

```
<input type="checkbox" name="a" value="a" <?php echo isset($_POST['b']) ? "checked" : ""; ?>/>
```

Now if `$_POST['b']` is set, the checkbox will be checked.

Also, you have `$_POST[b]`. The `b` should be in quotes. It should be `$_POST['b']`

Comment: well I want the value will be `n` if is not check and it will be `y` if is check` can I do the same from your code?

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're trying to do. Are you trying to get the value of the checkbox and do something with it in your code or are you trying to literally output the attribute `value="y/n"` to the HTML of the checkbox? If its the latter, you can add on to the echo. `echo isset($_POST['b']) ? 'checked value="y"' : 'value="n"';`

Answer (score 0):

tested code!

```
<form method="post">
   <input type="checkbox" name="b" <?php if (isset($_POST['b'])) echo "value='y'"; else echo "value='n'"; ?>/>
   <input type="submit" name="asd" value="asd">
</form>
```

So go with the following

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['b'])) echo "value='y'"; else echo "value='n'"; ?>
```

Comment: Well this is the same that I'm using and it doesn't work that is why I want to know.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me: 
  
      first: Giving the checkbox a default value
  
      then: assign the desired value only if the box is checked.

```
    <input type="hidden" name="b" value="n">
    <input type="checkbox" name="b" value="y" >
```

Answer (score 0):

*Approved by Deployment:

```
        <input type="radio" name="dep_approval_status" value="Approved"
            <?php 
                if ($deploy['dep_approval_status'] === "Approved")
                {
                    echo ' checked'; 
                }

            ?> 
        /> Yes, approved 

        <input type="radio" name="dep_approval_status" value="Not Approved"
            <?php 
                if ($deploy['dep_approval_status'] === "Not Approved")
                {
                    echo ' checked';
                }
            ?> 
        /> Not Approved
```